# Failed to load main class while executing war

Tags: java, maven, jar, war

I build my project using maven and generated a *.war file with the following content structure:

```
META-INF
- maven
-- net.avedo.spozz
--- Spozz-Webservice
---- pom.properties
---- pom.xml
- MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF
- classes
-- net
--- avedo
---- spozz
----- Spozz.class
----- models
------ ...
----- services
------ ...
-- psql-custom.properties
- lib
-- ...
- web.xml
```

If I now try to run the generated war file using `java -jar spozz.war`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class net.avedo.spozz.Spozz
```

What did I wrong? Please find the Manifest file and the definition of the maven-war-plugin in the `pom.xml` below.

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: awilhelm
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_51
Class-Path: javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar jetty-webapp-9.1.3.v20140225.j
 ar jetty-xml-9.1.3.v20140225.jar jetty-servlet-9.1.3.v20140225.jar je
 tty-security-9.1.3.v20140225.jar jetty-server-9.1.3.v20140225.jar jet
 ty-servlets-9.1.3.v20140225.jar jetty-continuation-9.1.3.v20140225.ja
 r jetty-http-9.1.3.v20140225.jar jetty-io-9.1.3.v20140225.jar jetty-j
 sp-9.1.3.v20140225.jar jetty-schemas-3.1.M0.jar javax.servlet.jsp-api
 -2.3.1.jar javax.servlet.jsp-2.3.2.jar javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v
 201105211821.jar javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.2.jar javax.el-3.0.0.jar 
 org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar jetty-util-9.1.3.v20140225.j
 ar jettison-1.3.5.jar stax-api-1.0.1.jar resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.j
 ar scannotation-1.0.3.jar javassist-3.12.1.GA.jar jboss-annotations-a
 pi_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar activation-1.1.jar jcip-annotations-1.0.j
 ar resteasy-client-3.0.6.Final.jar async-http-servlet-3.0-3.0.6.Final
 .jar jaxrs-api-3.0.6.Final.jar resteasy-servlet-initializer-3.0.6.Fin
 al.jar log4j-1.2.17.jar slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar c
 ommons-io-2.4.jar ormlite-jdbc-4.48.jar ormlite-core-4.48.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.1
Main-Class: net.avedo.spozz.Spozz
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

**Extract from pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>net.avedo.spozz.Spozz</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: A .war file has a different structure than a plain .jar file (and is supposed to be run by some webcontainer like Apache Tomcat).

Comment: And what does that actually mean for my project? How can I create a executable jar file from my project? Can I embedd my *.war file into a *.jar file that packs for example a jetty or tomcat environment? And when does this make sense? How can I do this? Many questions ... :-D

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know to launch a *.war* file as a Web application is with [Jetty Runner](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-runner.html):

1. Download [jetty-runner.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-runner/9.1.3.v20140225/jetty-runner-9.1.3.v20140225.jar)
2. Run `java -jar jetty-runner.jar spozz.war`
3. Access your Web application at *localhost:8080*

Comment: Tried this solution, but this does not seem to work with my war file, as I can start the service using `java -jar jetty-runner.jar --port 8083 spozz.war`, but as I access the service at `localhost:8083/services/users` I get an 404 error.

Comment: Can you post your web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

A normal jar file has its class files in the jar file root. Your class files are in WEB-INF\classes which is the normal position for a war (web application).

You could use the already mentioned jetty approach or relayout your archive file.

```
Jar
     Myclass.class
     Mymain.class
     META-INF
            manifest
```

But maybe you do not want an executable war. Then you have to create a Jar using maven.

Comment: I am currently not sure what I need. I am implementing a JAX-RS based REST service which should be accessed using different desktop and mobile applications. However, I thought it would be a good idea to offer a jsp servlet based webinterface too. But this does not seem to work as expected. What would I use in this case? War or jar files?

Comment: Because you are implementing a web service the WAR is here the way to go. JSP servlet based is not anymore the preferred technique. Maybe JSF, AngularJS, Wicket, .... Anyway this should be packed into your WAR. For a desktop application you could make a separate installable application or if you prefer the on in all WAR way may be webstart. You could pack your application in one WAR and a desktop app can be downloaded and installed from your server. And last but not least a mobile application could as well separatly packed and installed or you build some kind of html app for mobiles.

Comment: That does not make sense to me. I am implementing a REST webservice. Not a webapplication. This means that I send HTTP requests to the server to obtain the data I need within my application. So downloading a war and installing it on a local server, as well as wrapping it within an HTML app does not make sense. The whole application runs on one (virtually) server. Using the servlets I just wanted to offer a web interface.

Comment: Local server? Do you mean webstart? My suggestions were regarding the web interface to your server. WebStart you could use to include a desktop application in your WAR which could be installed. But you do not have to do it. I thought this was as well in your intention. WAR files are applications that need a server (tomcat, glassfish, jetty) to run. So why do you want a WAR executable? I think now that I missed something of your targets.

Comment: This is my first REST service I implement. I don't know if a war file is the best solution. I just found many examples that implement a REST service using JAX-RS and add a web interface using java servlets and pack all this into a war file. I thought it would be possible to generate a standalone war which could then be deployed to heroku or any other virtual server provider.